# rails 3.0.9 and escape_javascript stil not working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Running into a strange problem. I was sure that it used to work and is fixed in this version (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1553). I have a simple controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @msg = Message.new(params[:message])
      @msg.user_id = session[:user_id]
      @msg.room_hash = session[:current_room_hash]
      @msg.save!
    end
end
```

A form that submitting it:

```
<%= form_for Message.new, :html => {:id => "post_submit_form", :remote => true} do |f|%>
          <fieldset>
            <%= f.text_area :message, :id => 'post' %>

            <%= f.submit 'Post', :class => "button post" %>
          </fieldset>
      <% end %>
```

a create.js.erb file for rendering the html:

```
$('#pending_item').html(<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'stream_item'))%>);
```

Using jquery 1.6.1 and latest rails.js I keep getting parsererror in firebug by binding to ajax:error. I think is a problem with escape_javascript as if it just do the following it works great:

```
$('#pending_item').html('<h2>hello</h2>');
```

I know that partial works as it is use repeatedly to display the when the page loads. Additionaly if I just have:

```
<h2>hello</h2>
```

in the partial I have the same parsererror

I am sure I am using 3.0.9 as it says this when i start the app:

```
Rails 3.0.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `<%= escape_javascript(...) %>` part in quotes:

```
$('#pending_item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'stream_item'))%>");
```